# Rail Action View Page: Missing Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I just got a new computer at work and I have rails up and running with no problems.

But oddly I am missing the useful rails console that pops up whenever you run into an error in Rails. It is usually at the bottom of the page and is black.

Does anyone know how to get it to appear?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you after:

```
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end
```

Then use this in your view:

```
<% console %>
```

> Reference: https://github.com/rails/web-console

Comment: Its strange because I feel like I never had to do this in my older version of rails. It just use to have a live REPL in the error view that you could query methods and variable in the code up to that point.

Comment: I was looking at the reference you provided and I realized that I didn't have the web-console in the gem file (which apparently comes default) because the project I am on is older.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Better Errors.

https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors

Comment: I will have to check this out. It does seem better than what is usually shipped out with Rails.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the Rails console running ad infinitum in your terminal by opening a window and running `Rails C` or `Rails Console`. However, as Maximus said, if you are looking to use the console only when there is an error, you shoul add better_errors to your development environment; the error page itself has an active console window where you can run tests on the current state of your application.

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions.

-Dave

Comment: Yea the error page usually has that active console but mine for whatever reason does not (which I really do want)

Comment: Sometimes mine doesn't either, but I can click on `All Frames` using Better Errors and go through a couple items on the stack trace and sometimes one of those will open it up.